# How to retrieve a specific field from a list output?

Tags: abap

I don't have any developer rights in my SAP-System but I found a way to write some ABAP-Code in a tiny "User-Exit" box (I don't know if that's what you call it) inside a report.

I'm trying to submit a HR-Report and plug it's outcoming PERNR into that same report again.

There's a syntax-error that is telling me that `t_list` doesn't have a component with the Name `PERNR`.

What do I have to do in order to get this to work?

```
DATA: t_list TYPE TABLE OF abaplist WITH HEADER LINE,
      seltab TYPE TABLE OF rsparams,
      selline LIKE LINE OF seltab.
*I found out that the name of the selection field in the Report-GUI is "PNPPERNR" and tested it
selline-selname = 'PNPPERNR'.
selline-sign    = 'I'.
selline-option  = 'EQ'.

SUBMIT Y5000112
USING SELECTION-SET 'V1_TEST'
EXPORTING LIST TO MEMORY
AND RETURN.

CALL FUNCTION 'LIST_FROM_MEMORY'
TABLES
  listobject = t_list
EXCEPTIONS
  not_found = 1
  OTHERS = 2.
IF sy-subrc <> 0.
  WRITE 'Unable to get list from memory'.
ELSE.
  LOOP AT t_list.
*The Problem is here: how do I get the pnppernr out of t_list, it's the first column of the report output
    selline-low = t_list-pernr.
    append selline to seltab.
  ENDLOOP.

  SUBMIT Y5000112
  WITH SELECTION-TABLE seltab
  USING SELECTION-SET 'V2_TEST'
  AND RETURN.
ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the function module `LIST_TO_ASCI` to decode the contents of t_list into something readable. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12007700/218890) contains some sample code including the data types required. At this point, the data you're looking for will probably occur at the same column range in the output. Use the [standard substring access methods](http://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_04/helpdata/en/79/c55470b3dc11d5993800508b6b8b11/content.htm) - e. g. `line+42(21)` to obtain the part of the line you need.

Answer (score 0):

The vwegert's answer is more than useful! 
In [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632633/how-to-execute-report-given-the-results-of-a-previously-executed-report-in-abap) I forgot to mention LIST_TO_ASCI FM :)
The only thing I can add is that parsing of result lines has no universal solution and greatly depends on its structure. Usually it is done like:

```
LOOP AT t_list.
 SPLIT t_list AT '|' INTO <required_structure>.
 selline-low = <required_structure>-pernr.
 APPEND selline TO seltab.
ENDLOOP.
```

where <`required_structure> is your Y5000112 output structure. But this may be not so simple and may require additional manipulations.